# Home page down due to Woocommerce Wechat Pay plugin

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wechat

This is a shoppingmall manager. Our website is www.picknfit.com

Last Friday, we tried to add wechat pay for payment, and dowloaded Woocommerce Wechat Pay.

However, we received fatal error, and our homepage went down. Is there a solution to restore our website?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is another plugin declaring class `ILogHandler`.

**Step 1:**
Deactivate the plugin 'WordPress WooCommerce 微信支付插件' (wechat-weixin-payments-for-woocommerce) your website should be up and running.

**Step 2:**
Write to the plugin author explain him error. Ask him to namespace the class name.

Comment: Thank you for your response.

Comment: Do you know how I can deactivate the plugin?

Comment: @soobinmin Login to your site ( yoursite.com/wp-admin) and go to plugins menu, from the list, find the plugin and click deactivate link below that plugin.